# Initialize SDL_Surface* into a function

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-1.2

I want to initialize all my SDL_Surface into a function in order to have the clearest main possible, but it don't seems to work.
I'm doing it like this :

```
void setImages(SDL_Surface* mur, SDL_Surface* caisse, SDL_Surface* caisseOk, SDL_Surface* menu, SDL_Surface* objectif)
{
    mur = IMG_Load("images\\mur.jpg");
    caisse = IMG_Load("images\\caisse.jpg");
    caisseOk = IMG_Load("images\\caisse_ok.jpg");
    menu = IMG_Load("images\\menu.jpg");
    objectif = IMG_Load("images\\objectif.png");
}
```

And call it in the main like this :

```
setImages(mur, caisse, caisseOk, menu, objectif);
SDL_BlitSurface(menu, NULL, screen,&posMenu);
SDL_Flip(screen);
```

I tested, the IMG_Load works properly, but it don't seem to initialize my SDL_Surface outside of the function.
Is there a way to do this ? I guess there must be a way to initialize properly all of my SDL_Surface outside of the main...

The same way, if I'm doing the SDL_Init() and SDL_SetVideoMode() into a function, my screen will not be initialize too I guess ? Here's my function :

```
void initVideo(SDL_Surface* screen)
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) <0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Erreur lors de l'initialisation video : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,420,32,SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    if(screen == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Erreur lors de la configuration video : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

And my call into the main :

```
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL, *menu = NULL, *marioH = NULL, *marioD = NULL, *marioB = NULL, *marioG = NULL,
                *caisse = NULL, *caisseOk = NULL, *objectif = NULL, *mur = NULL;

    SDL_Rect posMenu, posMario;

    initVideo(screen);
```

Nothing send me an error, but nothing seems to happens. And the only things I found on the net was "Why do you want to do this ? It's useless". Is that right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C` uses pass by value for function argument passing.

It seems, your `setImages()` function changes the argument pointers itself.

Inside `setImages()` function, you can alter the *values* pointed by the passed pointers, not the pointers themselves. After returning, in `main()`, your pointers remain unchanged [uninitialized, if were before the call].

To achieve the desired functionality, you need to pass a *pointer to those pointers* [the *address* of those pointers] from your `main()`.

For example, you can change your `setImages()` function to

```
void setImages(SDL_Surface** mur, SDL_Surface** caisse, SDL_Surface** caisseOk, SDL_Surface** menu, SDL_Surface** objectif)
{
           //put some NULL check for sanity

    *mur = IMG_Load("images\\mur.jpg");
    *caisse = IMG_Load("images\\caisse.jpg");
   .
   .
}
```

and call from `main()` like

```
setImages(&mur, &caisse, &caisseOk, &menu, &objectif);
```

Comment: Something like `setImages(&mur, &caisse, &caisseOk, &menu, &objectif);` ?
I tried it but I get _"cannot convert 'SDL_Surface**' to 'SDL_Surface*' for argument '1' to 'void setImages(SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*)'|"_

I also tried `setImages(*mur, *caisse, *caisseOk, *menu, *objectif);` but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: @SoJJu i think you forgot to change the function definition.

Comment: I was writing this comment while you were updating your answer, we're too synchro ;)
I tried like you said, the code is building well, but it's still not displaying images... I must have another error somewhere else.
Anyway, thanks for the tips, it will be A LOT useful in the future I think !

Comment: Ok it worked, it was just missing my loop to pause the program and let him print the screen :)
Thanks again, have a good day.